# Web Service Response returns a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, internal-server-error

I have written my own web service which works fine stand alone. I'm calling this web service from another page, and at that time it returns a 500 Internal Server error. I'm going through this process for the 1st time and do not know what this means or why this happens. A preliminary search on Google shows a wide range of answers, although I couldnt find anything specific.

#### Heres my calling code -

```
List<string> inputList = new List<string>();
inputList.Add("F");
inputList.Add("B");    
List<string> resultList = new List<string>();
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/Helpers/MyService.asmx");
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/GetOutput\"");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = serializer.Serialize(inputList);
    streamWriter.Write(json);
}
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse(); *****ERROR HERE

string responseText = String.Empty;
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
resultList = serializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(responseText);
```

#### Heres my Web Service Code -

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

public class MyService: System.Web.Services.WebService
{        
    public string GetOutput(string jsonStr)
    {
        try
        {
            /*code to format jsonStr and send it along to another web service*/

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            string responseText = String.Empty;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            //this obj has a head & body
            ResponseObj response_obj = new ResponseObj();                
            response_obj = serializer.Deserialize<ResponseObj>(responseText);                
            List<string> Values = new List<string>();
            if (response_obj.head.result)
                return serializer.Serialize(response_obj.body);

            return "";                  
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
               throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the request/response with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)?

Comment: @jrummell No, I'll download it and try using it

Comment: Are you hosting this in IIS or inside a windows service exe?

Comment: @Matt I'm hosting this in IIS

Comment: @jrummell I installed fiddler and can see the request in the "Text" tab. However, I do not see a response there as the 500 error occurs. Can fiddler help me debug this issue further?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error basically means that your code crashes at some point. Put a print statement into the catch-block and see what the exception is. I suspect there is one, but now you wouldn't know because you aren't printing it.

Comment: @ZeroOne: Do you mean printing the Exception.Message?

Comment: @neuDev33: Just do `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());` and let us know what it prints out.

Comment: have a look at windows event log, I usually go check there if unsure what is happening

Comment: @ZeroOne Heres what it prints - "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetOutput()\r\n   at MyApp.Helpers.Test.GetSymbolInfo() in C:\\Users\\.....\\Helpers\\Test.asmx.cs:line 45"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that you can see details of the error at localhost/statistics/log, which showed me that there was an issue with my Web.config file. I commented the mentioned lines and the error went away making way for the next!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way to debug this is to attach visual studio to the IIS (menu debug/attach to Process...) so you can see step by step what is happening inside the web-service's code.

Comment: You mean Attach to "IIS Manager"? And then where will I be able to see what is happening inside the web-service's code?

Comment: You open your web-service solution, set a break point inside your code. Attach to w3wp.exe process (not to iis itself). Then you can use your client application to call the web-service and the debug session will start.

Comment: I see. However, I cannot see w3wp.exe in the list of Available Processes. Do I need to run it from somewhere prior?

Comment: Try to access the web-service site using a browser this will start the application pool. Then you may see w3wp.exe.